# passing callbacks with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, callback

Hey there I thought this would be a good idea, 
somehow it doesn't work. Can I make it work?
Or is it considered bad practice?

I have a kind of mathematic classroom-app, where a teacher can send problems to the students, and they answer them.

The idea is: count down 5 seconds before the problem is displayed,
then send the problem,
then count down a timer to keep track of max time for the students to use.

I thought I wouldn't need two separate countdown functions, as I could just pass two functions in (one containing what to do at every tick, the other being the actual cb).

But it crashes `count is not defined`

Any hints?

```
socket.on('sendTestProblem', function(msg) {
    countdown(function() {
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('timer', { countdown: count });  // crash on this line
      },
      function broadcastProblemToStudents() {
      socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('testProblem', {problem: msg.problem, timeLimit: timeLimit});
      socket.emit('problemSentToStudents');

      // after pre-countdown, start countdown for max answering time
      countdown(function countdownForAnswers() {
        io.in(socket.room).emit('timeLimit', {timeLimit: count});
      }, function timeOver() {
        io.in(socket.room).emit('timeOver');
      }, msg.timeLimit);
    })
  });

  function countdown(emit, cb, timeLimit) {
    console.log('countdown');
    var count = timeLimit || COUNTDOWN;
    var countdown = setInterval(function() {
      emit();  // emit this on every tick
      count--;
      if (count == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        cb();  // call this on 0
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `COUNTDOWN` from when you define `count` in your `countdown` function?

Comment: its defined at the very top of the file as constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you declare count variable in the scope on countdown function and it's not visible for "emit" callback. You should pass it as a parameter or declare in shared scope

```
    countdown(function(count) {
            socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('timer', { countdown: count });
          },
...

    emit(count);
```

Comment: the idea was to have it work with two different counts. one standard (5 sec pre-send) and one passed in (like 30sec for answering).
if i initialize it outside, i will have to use the same, won't i?

Comment: @user3787706 yup, you will use the same(actually in current example it not have to be a problem as callback will call successively, but shouldn't do it), so passing count variable as parameter to emit should be fine if I correct understand the problem